# Both exclude and include filter type (not_expression and expression) in filterExpression() filter on Google Data API using Python seems incorrect?

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to include an audience filter but exclude the internal traffic in that filter. Because "Test Data Filter Name" dimension is not available in audience creation filter in GA4, I am having to use it as an additional filter along with audienceName in Google Data API. Any idea why I am getting the same output for using only the Audience Name vs Audience Name excluding Internal Traffic.

This is what I have right now:

```
def get_report(start_date, end_date_delta):
    return client.run_report(RunReportRequest(
                    property = 'properties/322051858',
                    dimensions=[Dimension(name="date"),
                                Dimension(name='pageTitle'),
                                Dimension(name="sessionSourceMedium"),
                                Dimension(name="eventName"),
                                Dimension(name='customUser:GUID'),
                                Dimension(name='customEvent:asset'),
                                Dimension(name='customEvent:position')],
                    metrics=    [Metric(name="activeUsers"),
                                 Metric(name="totalUsers"),
                                 Metric(name="screenPageViews"),
                                 Metric(name="eventCount"),
                                 Metric(name="averageSessionDuration"),
                                 Metric(name="sessions")],
                    date_ranges = [DateRange(start_date= start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                                    end_date= (start_date+end_date_delta).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))],
                                            dimension_filter=FilterExpression(
                        and_group=FilterExpressionList(
                            expressions=[FilterExpression(
                                not_expression=FilterExpression(
                                   filter=Filter(field_name="testDataFilterName",
                                                  string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(value="Internal Traffic"))),
                                filter=Filter(field_name="audienceName",
                                          string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(value="Bot and Ashburn/Boydton Filter"))
                            )]

                        )
                    ),
                    limit = 100000))
```

I have attached the data from GA4 Dashbboard to show the numbers for both the filters should have been different.

[image]